# Debugging a MYSQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

The following is a "forgot password" script I have on my site.   I have one MYSQL table where I store the email addresses of users.  It is called 'members' and has 2 columns: 'user' (users' email addresses) and 'pass' (their passwords).

The email address adamjwilkins1604@gmail.com exists in the members table. When I input this email address in the forgot password form, I get this error.  I am having a lot of trouble debugging this.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1
```

Forgot password script:

```
<?php // forgot_password.php
include_once 'header.php';

if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
    { // Handle the form.
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) 
        {
        $uid = FALSE;
        echo 'You forgot to enter your registered email address!';    
        }
        else 
            {
            // Check for the existence of the inputted email address.
            $email = trim(sanitizeString($_POST['email']));
            $result = queryMysql("SELECT user FROM members WHERE user='$email'");
                if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
                    {
                    // Retrieve the user's email address
                    list($uid) = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_NUM);
                    }
                    else 
                        {
                        echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">The submitted email address does not match those on file!</font></p>';
                        $uid = FALSE;
                        }
            }

        if ($uid)
            {
            $p = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(),1)),3,10);
            $result = queryMysql("UPDATE members SET pass=SHA('$p') WHERE user = $uid");
            if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) 
                {
                // If it ran OK, send an email.
                $email = trim(sanitizeString($_POST['email']));
                $body = "Your password has been temporarily changed to '$p'. Please log in using this password and your username.";
                mail ($email, 'Your temporary password.', $body, 'From: admin@mywebsite.com');
                echo '<h3>Your password has been changed. You will receive the new, temporary password at the email address with which you registered. Once you have logged in with this password, you may change it by clicking on the "change password" link.</h3>';
                mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.
                }
                else
                    {
                    // If it did not run OK.
                    echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">Your password could not be changed due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</font></p>';
                    }
            }
                else // Failed the validation test.
                    {
                    echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">Please try again.</font></p>';
                    }
    } // End of the main Submit conditional.
?>

<h1>Reset Your Password</h1>
<p>Enter your email address below and your password will be reset.</p>
<form action="forgot_password.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<p><b>Your registered email address:</b> <input type="text" name="email" size="20" maxlength="40" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>" /></p>
</fieldset>
<div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reset My Password" /></div>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try outputting the generated query? Also [the mysql extension is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should switch to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and use prepared statements.

Comment: `sanitizeString()` is probably wrong,

Comment: As an aside, email addresses aren't the best PK, I'd stick with an Auto-Inc INT.

Comment: Problem is, as a beginner, I am learning from the latest version of a book (O'Reilly's PHP guide) and it is not updated for mysqli.  Programming language gets deprecated within a few months of books getting published.

Comment: have you tried removing the single quotes from the `$email` or `echo` it to see what actually being passed to the query?

Comment: SLaks, sanitizeString works -- it is a function I created that is being included via include_once 'header.php';

Comment: @user3388726 did you try to fetch result with this

$result = queryMysql("SELECT user FROM members WHERE user='".$email."'");

also echo query and try to run direct on phpmyadmin then see what error you will get 

or can you plase paste your echo query sql statement

Comment: @user3388726 Being defined and well-written are two different things. The fact that you re-invented the wheel tells me your sanitization function probably is incorrect.

Comment: @user3388726 have you checked your code without your santizer? like '$email = $_POST['email']';

Comment: This is wha the sanitizeString function does, please let me know if it is sufficient:
function sanitizeString($var)
{
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    return mysql_real_escape_string($var);
}

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to quote `$uid` in your `UPDATE` statement. And you forgot to escape it as well.